# Obtaining an image upon ViewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

The button functionality works, if the score passes 5 it works, and if I set the variable score equal to a number greater than it already is, it saves that high score, how do I get it to increment and save the high score when the button is clicked (if the button went higher than the high score)?

If I set score equal to 100 explicitly, and then reset it to a lower number, say 14, the screen will still display 100. How do I get this to use the button so I don't have to use the variable to set the number, let's say if the user clicks the button 120 times, the screen text will be 120, not 100?

Thank you.

```
var score = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//0...n
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
//image
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
//adds 1
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    ++score
    textLabel.text = String(score)

    if textLabel.text >= "5" {
        image.image = UIImage(named: "win")
    }
}

func newScore() -> Int {
    var highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

    if score > highScore {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        highScore = score
    }
    return highScore
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    textLabel.text = String(newScore())

    if textLabel.text >= "5" {
        image.image = UIImage(named: "win")
    }

    textLabel.text = String(newScore())
}
```

Comment: why are you using textLabel.text to detect your score to determine if the user wins? You already have a property for that: `score`

Comment: Because it's what displays on the UI. @Bluehound

Comment: @JustinRose I believe he's saying that this: `if textLabel.text >= "5"` should be this: `if score >= 5`

Comment: Other than that, I don't really understand your question...

Comment: How do I get the score to leave off at the number it was at instead of 0? let's say the new highscore is 15, how do I get it to leave off at 15, and not 0? @LyndseyScott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an observer to the `score` property so when it is set you can check the score and update the UI accordingly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!


var score: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
    didSet  {
        updateScore()
    }
}

func updateScore() {
    if score > 5 {
        println("win")
    }

    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

    checkHighScore()
}

func checkHighScore() {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if score > defaults.integerForKey("highscore") {
        defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateScore()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    score++
}
```

Comment: How do I get the highscore to leave off of the highscore number, not the score number? So if the highscore was 15, it wouldnt start from 0, but from 15

Comment: You want the text label to start at the high score?

Comment: Yes, exactly. if the high score was 15, when the app was launched it would start counting at 16....n @Bluehound

Comment: Check the updated answer. Just set your score to equal the NSUserdefault integerForKey initially. If highscore exists it will equal the highscore. If highscore is not set it will equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

Track the number of button clicks in another variable, like `buttonClicks`, incrementing it each time the user clicks the button. Then under `addButton` do

`textLabel.text = String(buttonClicks)`